# Sort selected text from Visual Studio context menu

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, sorting, visual-studio-addins

Currently VS has a very useful feature: sort usings (C#).

I want the same functionality for any random text, for example - XML nodes in config files.

How complex to implement that? VS addin, right? Is it possible to call some VS API which is used for sorting usings?

Comment: Quick and dirty: copy into Notepad++, select Edit > Line Operations, click the way you would like to sort and then copy back into Visual Studio

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just found a good free addon: [Menees VS Tools 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/42de112b-3ecf-4a9e-94f0-2b5efb053aa6) (or [2010 ver](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8EF48A25-B1A2-498F-9B0A-70E8FD38A675)) - does exactly that and a few more text tricks. There was a few minor negatives when I installed it, but after leaving a comment on the review page it got fixed within days. Waay to go! =)

There is a 2017 version now: [Menees VS Tools 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BillMenees.MeneesVSTools2017)

Comment: @zdf had the perfect answer, as it's something directly built into Studio.

Answer (score 43):

**VS 2019** & **VS 2022**:

1. **Select lines**. The last selected line is where the cursor is - the line is taken into account even if it is empty and there is no visible selection.
2. **<kbd>Shift + Alt + L</kbd>, <kbd>Shift + Alt + S</kbd>** => Ascending sort.
3. **<kbd>Shift + Alt + L</kbd>, <kbd>Shift + Alt + S</kbd>** (same selection same keys) => Descending sort.

The command can also be invoked from menu (@sharpener): ***Edit*** | ***Advanced*** | ***Sort Lines***

This shortcut applies to the most used scheme: the Visual C++ 6 keyboard mapping scheme (and possibly other schemes). You can check your scheme in ***Options | Keyboard | Apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme:***.

You can check the shortcut in ***Options | Keyboard | Show commands containing: Edit.SortLines | Shortcuts for the selected command:***.

Comment: Or: `Edit | Advanced | Sort Lines` if the shortcuts are assigned to something else...

Comment: More upvotes for this, it's built into VS now, this is what most people will be looking for! (Thankfully this answer is displayed *within* google.)

Comment: @zdf - now if you knew which commands this represented in VS, that would be even handier, as we could make our own toolbar button for it.

Comment: If you want to override the keyboard shortcut; In Visual Studio 2019/2022 this can be found under the keyboard commands key `Edit.SortLines`.

Same keybinding sorts asc/desc depending on current selection text.

Comment: I don't understand the " (same selection same keys) => Descending sort." part,  I tried to do it twice thinking it will change sort direction.  But it did not.  Could anyone explain ?  Thanks very much.

Comment: @EBDS Either you're doing something wrong or you have different command bindings. To check the bindings, go to `Tools | Customize | Keyboard... | Show commands containing: Edit.SortLines`. And check `Shortcuts for selected command:`.

Answer (score 26):

A nice AddOn for Visual Studio is [Code Maid](http://www.codemaid.net/)

You select some lines and chose from Context Menu "Sort Lines"

[image]

And voilá, your lines are sorted nicely in alphabetical order:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for Code Maid 10.2 on VisualStudio 2013 when editing a C++ source file. The selected lines are left unchanged.

Answer (score 24):

**Edit:** Note that this solution does not work on VS2013 or higher, since support for macros was removed.

You don't necessarily need to code a VS addin to do this: Visual Studio has macros built in. To get started, use Tools, Macros, Record Temporary Macro.

Here's a 'Sort Lines' command I hacked together based on the code that Record Temporary Macro gave me:

```
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE

Public Module TimModule
    Sub SortLines()
        Dim Selection As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
        Dim Lines() As String = Selection.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, Chr(13)).Split(Chr(13))
        Array.Sort(Lines)
        DTE.UndoContext.Open("Sort Lines")
        ' Edit - see comments
        ' Selection.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Lines)
        Selection.Delete
        Selection.Insert(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Lines)) 
        DTE.UndoContext.Close()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: You are using TextSelection.Text property to change the text. This is usually a reason of a very slow execution. It may take even several seconds. The better way is to use TextSelection.Insert and Delete methods. I haven't tested it but I recommend to replace line:
Selection.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Lines)
with 2 lines:
Selection.Delete
Selection.Insert(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Lines))

Then you can place your macro on toolbar or menu (http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/7) or assign key shortcut to it (http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/8)

Comment: @Peter, thanks. I didn't spend long writing this - if you add an answer to the OP I'll vote it up

Comment: Peter's suggestion changed my running time from ~30 seconds to nearly instantaneous, and also stopped some garbage-lines from being generated.

Comment: Very helpfull, I would suggest slight modification to avoid empty line from the end of the selection mixing with the result and strange behaviour when only part of one line is selected:

Dim count As Integer = Lines.Length

If Lines.GetValue(count - 1) = "" Then count = count - 1

If count < 2 Then Exit Sub

Array.Sort(Lines, 0, count)

Comment: This does not work for me: when I debug this macro, the lines are not split — the length of Lines array is 1.

Comment: Ok, I am on the track: my document uses uses LF for line endings (aka '\n'). So the Environment.NewLine is not the same as my line separators. Is there a way to access a line separator on a per file basis? When I open the files with inconsistent line endings VS asks if I want to normalize them, so I assume, there might be a property of a currently opened document, that holds a line separator. Does anyone now how to find it?

Comment: My current workaround is to use Chr(10) instead of Environment.NewLine.

Comment: VS 2012 has dropped support for macros.

Answer (score 7):

This comes up at the top of searches still so I'll add this latest solution.  If you are running a current VS Code (and why wouldn't you?) you can use the built-in sorter by hitting ctrl-shift-p (Mac is cmd-shift-p) and type "sort" in the subsequent search box.  There are many options.

Answer (score 6):

You can copy the code into Sublime Text, select the section of code and hit F9 (or go to Edit > Sort Lines).  You can then copy it back into Visual Studio.

Comment: good idea. same with emacs: mark region, then Alt-X sort-lines

Comment: sadly, thats what i do ...but wanted to skip the copy paste :)

Answer (score 5):

I am personally using the [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) extension by Mads Kristensen.
You just select the lines you want to sort and Alt+3 or Alt+4 (asc/desc).