# How do I sort lines of code alphabetically in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort selected text from Visual Studio context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350793/sort-selected-text-from-visual-studio-context-menu)

I have some **lines** of code I wish to sort alphabetically, nothing clever.

I wish to just select the lines, and then sort them.  (I could copy them into Excel then sort and copy them back, but there must be a better way)

This is the bit of code I am trying to time, in real life it is a lot longer…

```
sortingColumnOverrides: new Dictionary<Enum, Enum>()
{
   {Cols.SimulationPrice,Cols.SimulationPriceRange},                
   {Cols.BaselineEffectivePrice, Cols.BaselineEffectivePriceRange},                
   {Cols.SimulationEffectivePrice, Cols.SimulationEffectivePriceRange},                
   {Cols.SimulationCost, Cols.SimulationCostRange},                
   {Cols.BaselinePrice,Cols.BaselinePriceRange},                
   {Cols.BaselineCost,Cols.BaselineCostRange},                
   {Cols.PriceLiftAbs, Cols.SimulationPriceChangeRange},                
   {Cols.PriceLiftPct, Cols.SimulationPriceChangePercentRange},                
   {Cols.BaselinePricePerUOM, Cols.BaselinePricePerUOMRange},                
   {Cols.SimulationPricePerUOM, Cols.SimulationPricePerUOMRange},   
   //lots more lines like these....
}
```

More marks, if there is a easy way to stop the sort at the first ",", but that would just be icing on the cake.

(Other questions in the past of ask about the more complex task of sorting methods by name etc.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350793/sort-selected-text-from-visual-studio-context-menu

Answer (score 3):

You have an add-on for this: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/D6678A1F-C700-4532-8C5E-A799D875063D?SRC=VSIDE

Comment: Visual Assist X cost money, however there is a free tail version.   But I would not trust it not to mess up my ReSparper install.